# Does vimeo provide the service/api of creating the video from the given images?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am developing an application in which i need to create the video from the images. Currently i am doing this with java JMF. I then need to upload the video to the vimeo using the vimeo api.
So, if anyone can share the info that,

"***Does vimeo provide the service/api of creating the video from the given images?***"

If yes, pls provide some helpful link to know more about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[No, it does not](https://developer.vimeo.com/api). You should use something like [QuickTime Pro](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/extending/), or [istopmotion](http://boinx.com/istopmotion/mac/).

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo does provide an API
https://developer.vimeo.com/api

As of July 17 2014
http://vimeoapi.tumblr.com/tagged/vimeo-api

But it doesn't appear to have the functionality you want. At least I couldn't find it with a cursory search. In fact it looks very primitive.

You should consider using some other piece of software for converting images to video, then uploading that.